# How can I join a conference?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

My use case is similar to the example from the docs, exepct that I make a call to the moderator. One function is starting the conference:

```
dial.conference(
      {
        startConferenceOnEnter: false,
      },
      'test',
    );
```

Another function is calling the moderator with

```
this.twilioClient.calls.create();
```

The Moderator is asked if he wants to join. In the response action I try to connect to the ongoing conference, but this starts a new conference.

```
dial.conference(
      {
        startConferenceOnEnter: true,
        endConferenceOnExit: true,
      },
      'test',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks right, if you pass a URL for the statusCallback parameter you can see information around your conference.

david

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).